# Robots.txt: allow all access but 2 directories

Tags: robots.txt

I need to let all agents visit all my site and its subdirectories, but two directories:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /disable_dir_1/
Disallow: /disable_dir_2/
```

Is this the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools to do that automatically:
[robots.txt generator](http://www.mcanerin.com/EN/search-engine/robots-txt.asp)

Anyway, your approach is OK, but I strongly recommend following Google's recommendations in that matter:
[Google robots.txt explanation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449)